# Elegant solution in TypeScript for object mappers?

Tags: typescript

So, like everyone else, i'm talking to an API. And this API returns me something like this:

```
{
  "name": "FooBar",
  "status": "active",
  "long_description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "created_at": "1999-01-01 12:00:00"
}
```

On all my classes, i have a public static method like this:

```
public static fromApiResult(result: any): MyRecord {
    const myRecord = new MyRecord();
    myRecord.name = result.name;
    myRecord.status = result.status;
    myRecord.longDescription = result.long_description;

    if (result.created_at) {
        myRecord.createdAt = new Date(result.created_at);
    }

    return myRecord;
}
```

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize your api is using snake_case. But for the timestamp question, I don't think TS will create new Date object for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public static fromApiResult(result: any): MyRecord {
    const myRecord = Object.assign(new MyRecord(), result) as MyRecord;

    if (result.created_at) {
        myRecord.createdAt = new Date(result.created_at);
    }

    return myRecord;
}
```

Not much of a change, but [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) will save you some code when you just want to copy it from the object to the class instance.

---

#### Edit

The [definitions for the assign method](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4461) are:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
    assign<T, U, V>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V): T & U & V;
    assign<T, U, V, W>(target: T, source1: U, source2: V, source3: W): T & U & V & W;
    assign(target: any, ...sources: any[]): any;

    ...
}
```

Because the `result` in your code is of type `any` it means that the first signature will return: `MyRecord & any` which is just `any`.
Because you probably want to have `myRecord` as `MyRecord` you need to cast.

Another option of course is:

```
const myRecord = Object.assign(new MyRecord(), result as MyRecord);
```

---

#### 2nd edit

You can go over all properties and create a new object with a camelcase props and then use `Object.assign`:

```
function toCamelCase(obj: any) {
    const cloned = {};

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        cloned[key.replace(/(\_\w)/g, function (m) { return m[1].toUpperCase(); })] = obj[key]; 
    });

    return cloned;
}

public static fromApiResult(result: any): MyRecord {
    const myRecord = Object.assign(new MyRecord(), toCamelCase(result)) as MyRecord;

    if (result.created_at) {
        myRecord.createdAt = new Date(result.created_at);
    }

    return myRecord;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It blindly copies? I don't understand the need for the cast there.

Comment: Yeah, it will just copy the properties in `result` to the instance of `MyRecord`, as for the cast, you might not need it

Comment: Check my revised answer regarding the casting part

Comment: Doesn't really work for me because i'm using snake_case in the API. But it's certainly useful for people adopting camelCase in their API!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed that part... Check the 2nd edit of my answer